# Unique ManyToMany selection

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, unique

I have 2 tables with a ManyToMany relation:

```
Image {id, name, score}

Tag {id, name}

Images_Tags {image_id, tag_id}
```

I want to select 3 specific tags by their Ids (20, 21, 22) and for each tag, select the highest scored image tagged with this tag.

This is what I've came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT t.id AS tag_id, t.name AS tag_name, i.* FROM `acme_tag` t
  LEFT JOIN `acme_images_tags` r ON t.id = r.tag_id
  LEFT JOIN `acme_images` i ON i.id = r.image_id
  WHERE t.id IN (20, 21, 22)
  ORDER BY i.score DESC
) f
GROUP BY f.tag_id
```

**The tricky part** I'm trying to solve, is that when 2 tags have the **same** highest-scored image, it should choose the second highest-scored image to avoid duplicate images.

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each image, choose which of the three tags is best.  Then choose the best among those.

You can choose the best for each image with the following trick in MySQL:

```
 select i.id, max(score) as maxscore,
        substring_index(group_concat(it.tag_id order by score desc, rand()), ',', 1) as prefTag
 from image i join
      acme_images_tags it
      on i.id = it.image_id and
         it.tag_id in (20, 21, 22)
 group by i.id;
```

The complicated expression for `prefTag` chooses the highest scoring tag for each image.  The `rand()` is there to handle ties, to be sure that all tags with an equivalent best score have an equal chance.

You can then choose the best image for each tag, using the same idea:

```
select prefTag,
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by maxscore desc), ',', 1) as image_id
from (select i.id, max(score) as maxscore,
             substring_index(group_concat(it.tag_id order by score desc, rand()), ',', 1) as prefTag
      from image i join
           acme_images_tags it
           on i.id = it.image_id and
              it.tag_id in (20, 21, 22)
      group by i.id
     ) t
group by prefTag
```

This is simpler (but equivalent) to my earlier solution which used `union all`.  I am leaving that below.

```
(select i.id, max(score) as maxscore,
        substring_index(group_concat(it.tag_id order by score desc), ',', 1) as prefTag
 from image i join
      acme_images_tags it
      on i.id = it.image_id and
         it.tag_id in (20, 21, 22)
 group by i.id
 having preftag = 20
 order by maxscore desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select i.id, max(score) as maxscore,
        substring_index(group_concat(it.tag_id order by score desc), ',', 1) as prefTag
 from image i join
      acme_images_tags it
      on i.id = it.image_id and
         it.tag_id in (20, 21, 22)
 group by i.id
 having preftag = 21
 order by maxscore desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select i.id, max(score) as maxscore,
        substring_index(group_concat(it.tag_id order by score desc), ',', 1) as prefTag
 from image i join
      acme_images_tags it
      on i.id = it.image_id and
         it.tag_id in (20, 21, 22)
 group by i.id
 having preftag = 22
 order by maxscore desc
 limit 1
)
```

Comment: thanks, but if I have 2 tags with the same highest scored image, I'll end up with 2 identical images

Comment: @tamir . . . No, you will not.  The tag for each image is determined first.  An image cannot appear on two tags.

Comment: hmm.. when I tested the old code (before the edit) I got the same image for 2 different tags. The new code gives me an "Unknown column 'tag_id' in 'field list'" error

Comment: @tamir . . . Now that I think of it, the original code depended on the results being the same in the three subqueries.  But, MySQL does not guarantee a stable sort, so the results could differ (this could be fixed by adding `tag_id` to the sort criteria.  I fixed the problem with the edited version, which seems to be superior.

Comment: btw, the `rand()` inside the `order by` makes the result sometimes only 2 images instead of 3, so I omitted it and it works fine

Comment: @tamir . . . Be sure you have `order by score desc`.  It was ordering by score ascending and then random.

Comment: I have it that way and it still gives me partial results half of the time

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about your if tie pick second place idea, I think you want the max period right?
This is untested but this might work, use a subquery to get the max score per image.

```
SELECT t.id AS tag_id, t.name AS tag_name
FROM `acme_tag` t
LEFT JOIN `acme_images_tags` r ON t.id = r.tag_id
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id, max(score) from image group by id) AS max_i 
ON max_i.id = r.image_id
WHERE t.id IN (20, 21, 22)
```

Comment: thanks, but how is that preventing from 2 tags having the same max-scored image?